# Is it possible to run declarative script in Execute Shell section?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Weird situation I got caught into! I need to run a pipeline at the end of the freestyle job. So I found [PostBuildScript](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuildscript/) to run something at the end of freestyle jobs. [PostBuildScript](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuildscript/) only allows shell and groovy, but my post build task is kind of a small pipeline declarative script.

Here's the script which I want to run into **Execute Shell** of [PostBuildScript](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuildscript/):

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            git(url: 'https://gitlab/user/auto-test.git', credentialsId: '0ca6a4877f21')
            sh "chmod +x ./SOWTest/build.sh"
            sh "./SOWTest/build.sh SOWTest/config.ini"
        }
        post {
            always {
                emailext attachLog: true,
                    attachmentsPattern: "**/reports/*.html",
                    mimeType: "text/html",
                    to: "user@company.com",
                    subject: "Automated Regression Test - Build [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]",
                    body: '''<html> ... </html>'''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is it possible to run this declarative script inside this **Execute Shell** of [PostBuildScript](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuildscript/)?

[image: Script may look like this in Execute Shell]

Or if any conversion is possible of the declarative script to shell/groovy? Because I completely blocked on email part as well as decision part whether the tests failed or succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach would be to convert the freestyle jobs into a pipeline project and then execute/add the necessary stages inside it. With this you will be able to execute conditions based on previous stages if they were successful or not and will be maintainable.

To Generate a Jenkinsfile for a pipeline from a Freestyle project please refere below link
https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/pipelines/declarative-pipeline-migration-assistant#_generating_a_jenkinsfile_from_a_freestyle_project.
As you said, you do not have an option to convert the existing freestyle project to pipeline, the option for you would be to write your code in individual shell scripts and dont have it in pipeline. Get indivual scripts result status and use that result status in further scripts.
For sending email :you can solve this issue by just writing a simple python script of sending email and include it on your shell script as below: 
In your custom postjob.sh script execute your custom python script for sending email:
Just make sure the python executable is in your PATH environment variable

```
#!/bin/sh
python send_Email.py
```

send_Email.py :

```
print ("Email generation script")
...
```

**All possible solutions:**

- Convert existing freestyle project to pipeline project.
- If converting to pipeline project is not a possibilty then execute a shell  script 
   calling internallay all the scripts you used in pipeline and based on the overall 
  result, set the revert /upstream etc as shown in the example. This option fits 
  your usecase.
- Create  a separate pipeline job and trigger this job from your freestyle 
  project. Under Post-build Actions of your freestyle project select 
  "Build Other projects" and give your pipeline job.

Comment: Exactly! this was the first thing in my mind when I designed the test pipeline script, but after the implementation, got to know the main project is as freestyle job! I stuck there! And this is the constraint that existing job can not be converted to pipeline script just because of my test stage.

Comment: @Khan ok, is there not a possibiltiy to migrate this to a new pipeline job?If this is not the condition, then you should write your code  in  individual shell scripts and dont have it in pipeline. Get indivual scripts result status and use that result status in further scripts.

Comment: Yeah.. I could not migrate right now. And whatever you suggesting, I am trying to do so. But dont know how email-ext will work in shell!

Comment: @Khan : you can solve the email issue by just writing a simple python script of sending email and include it on your shell script. It would solve your problem.I will update my answer with how to do this

Comment: @Khan: One more option you have: Create this as a separate pipeline job and trigger this job from your freestyle project. Under Post-build Actions of your freestyle project select "Build Other projects" and give your pipeline job. But the drawback of this model would be you need to get your pre-requisites again which you had taken in the freestyle project. But if this is not the case then you can use this option. I hope I have given all possibilities now;-)

Comment: +1 for the suggestions. and the solutions you're proposing require lot of efforts. Still doing something similar only, though sending the mail and then then deciding whether the tests got failed or succeeded will still be tricky part.

Comment: @khan : what about this option :Create this as a separate pipeline job and trigger this job from your freestyle project. Under Post-build Actions of your freestyle project select "Build Other projects" and give your pipeline job. Regrading othe rpoint which you mentioned that it requires efforts : I just created a simple shell file and execute python scripts inside it and it worked fine for me and efforts were not high but yes i knew python language in that case

Comment: I have tried this as well, but to sending the results back to the upstream job or reverting back (restore) the build which is done by upstream job if tests are failing, it becomes messy.

Comment: @Khan : Okay , then I feel the only option for you is to execute a shell script calling internallay all the scripts you used in pipeline and based on the overall result, set the revert /upstream etc.

Comment: Now this is what I did.. :) You could update your answer with this one.. or all the possible solutions.

Comment: @Khan , Thanks, I updated the answer with all possible solutions.